# "(node:18748) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental." when trying to run node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run a backend server for my full stack application but when I try to run `node .\index.js` on my terminal, I get this error

```
(node:18748) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/Users/Amman/dunder-mifflin/server/index.js:1
const express = require('express')
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
(node:18748) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///C:/Users/Amman/dunder-mifflin/server/index.js:1
const express = require('express')
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/Amman/dunder-mifflin/server/index.js:1:17
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
```

I tried to find solutions to fix it online but none matched what I'm having so I have no clue what's going on.

This is my index.js code

```
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const mysql = require('mysql')
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Okay, and does your package.json say that your project is module-based? (in which case your imports should use modern `import` syntax, not the commonjs `require` syntax)

Comment: Yes, removed that and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update your nodejs version. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/download and check latest Longterm Support(LTS) version if possible